# Extending Product Select Options block is not applying

Tags: layout, blocks, overrides, ce-1.9.1.0

I have `app\code\local\Etre\Categories\Block\Rewrite\Catalog\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php` extending `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select` like this:

```
<?php
class Etre_Categories_Block_Rewrite_Catalog_Product_View_Options_Type_Select
    extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select{
    /**
     * Return html for control element
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValuesHtml()
    {
        die('Now we can continue.');
    }
}
```

In `app\code\local\Etre\Categories\etc\config.xml` I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Etre_Categories>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Etre_Categories>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <etre_categories>
                <class>Etre_Categories_Block</class>
            </etre_categories>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_options_type_select>Etre_Categories_Block_Rewrite_Catalog_Product_View_Options_Type_Select</product_view_options_type_select>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
```

The best that I know how to I have checked for conflicts but have not found any.

Comment: please check compiler is enable or not?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do not use the compiler (it is turned off) and cache is already disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Is your module config XML even loading? Create some invalid syntax and see if the system errors out. Make sure that developer mode is enabled.

Beyond this, what are you trying to accomplish?